# What is the native representation for colors in modern web browser engines?

Tags: html, css, browser, colors, cross-browser

What is the native representation for colors in modern web browser engines?

Specifically:

Do they use hex (e.g. #123456), color names (e.g. 'black'), RGB, HSL, or something else?

If the representation differs by different engines, please indicate.  Also, if it differs if alpha is specified, please also indicate.

Answer (score 0):

If its a basic color name, then you can just say it. Go to the CSS page and type:

```
.a-class {
    color:black;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);

}
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I'm after.  I'm asking how the color is represented within the browser engine.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers don't care if you use names, hex codes, RGB, or HSL for fully opaque colors. **Pick the one that makes the most sense for your use case.**

Eg if you're doing a quick prototype use names, if you need to do lots of color transforms use HSL. If you need transparency you must use **RGBA** or **HSLA** notation.

Be aware that browser makers get to decide what actual color is produced when you ask for `teal` or `red` so if you're working with specific brand colors Hex/RGB/HSL is likely better.

To the best of my knowledge all browsers represent CSS colors the same way ([this wasn't always the case](https://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/)). *Note: different screen calibrations will make colors appear different on individual devices)*

However, [color in images](https://cameratico.com/guides/web-browser-color-management-guide/) is very different and based on the browser, OS, device (display abilities), and embedded color profiles.

***Edit:***  Browser engines to the best of my knowledge are [converting to sRGB](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#resolving-color-values) colorspace as that's the display output of 99% of places where browsers run.

Comment: Thank you Bryce. I understand.  But I'm asking how the browser engines represent the colors natively.

Comment: Browsers don't natively represent colors the device display does...

Comment: Every browser represents colors in variables.

Comment: Are you asking what [Bit Depth](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/monitor4.htm) browsers use? Typically the OS layer sits between the application and the monitor to decide what color is displayed. The app (browser in this case) sends the OS a color definition and that's translated to hardware for display.

Comment: No, not what bit-depth either.  What representational format does the browser use to store colors?

Comment: According to the [Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#resolving-color-values) its sRGB. This is why you calibrate your monitor not your browser.

Comment: Thank you. The link to that spec is *very* helpful!  Now the big question is: Do the currently browser engines follow that spec in how they represent the data internally?